# Placing figure captions at the bottom

Tags: floats, positioning, captions

How do I get the captions for my figures to be placed at the bottom of the picture, just like the captions for tables?

Comment: Place the `\caption` command below the `\inculdegraphics` command?

Comment: Ohhh, hahaha. I never thought the order would be important. Thanks Seamus!

Comment: @Seamus: Please write an answer, so that this question can go off the unanswered list.

Comment: The order is important. Except if you use the `float` package and restyle the standard float, then the order is given by the style. Note that by default the distance is set up for captions which are placed below the image or table. For top captions use `\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\abovecaptionskip}\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}` inside the specific float environment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of manually changing the placement of all `\caption` commands, you may load the [floatrow](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/floatrow.html) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
% \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
(Figure content)
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 26):

Whether you place `\caption` above or below the `\includegraphics` command (or whatever) affects whether the caption appears above or below the included graphic.

Also note that the `\label` should go below the `\caption`.